# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to select data from joined tables.

I'm getting an error Warning:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given

This is the code:

```
<?php

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT exercicios.nome_exercicio AS  nome_exc , exercicios.repeticoes_exercicio  AS rep_exc , exercicios.serie  AS serie_exc FROM exercicios 
    INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = exercicios.id_usuario
    WHERE id_usuario  = usuarios.id_usuario
");

if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0) {
    while ($exercicio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-responsive'>

<tr><td></td><td>Nome</td><td>Repetições</td><td>Série</td></tr>

<td>'".$exercicio['nome_exc']."'</td>
<td>'".$exercicio['rep_exc']."'</td>
<td>'".$exercicio['serie_exc']."'</td>


</table></div> ";
    }
} else {
    echo "Seu instrutor ainda não cadastrou exercícios";
}
```

Comment: two things:- connection code is missed.  and show us the output of `var_dump($consulta);` put it just after query and check.   also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check for errors.

Comment: can you please run the query in mysql and check for error, is that where condition correct ? please confirm it

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` return `mysqli_result` on success but boolean false on failure ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)), that means your query is failed and returning boolean false. Check your query statement and MySQL table.

**Try this SQL:**

```
SELECT exercicios.nome_exercicio AS nome_exc,
   exercicios.repeticoes_exercicio AS rep_exc,
   exercicios.serie AS serie_exc 
FROM exercicios
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = exercicios.id_usuario
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like you have problem in your query .

Valid Query is -:

```
SELECT exercicios.nome_exercicio AS nome_exc,
   exercicios.repeticoes_exercicio AS rep_exc,
   exercicios.serie AS serie_exc 
FROM exercicios
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = exercicios.id_usuario
```

Comment: It's working! I want to thanks everyone!